# Android tablet with embedded VideoView loses video on rotation

Tags: android, video, orientation-changes, android-videoview

I'm looking for a solution to continue playing a video for a URL (*.mp4/playlist.m3u8) in an embedded VideoView on a tablet when the device is rotated.
Currently, the video is being restarted on rotation using onPause() and onResume().

As I understand it, a lot of solutions require using `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`, but Android's developer site suggests using this only as a last resort.
See [Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html).

> This technique should be considered a last resort when you must avoid restarts due to a configuration change and is not recommended for most applications.

Is there another way to do this? How would I go about keeping the video playing through rotation like how a Phone device does when using Intents?

**Edit:** I also want to mention that the other reason I am avoiding use of `android:configChanges` is because I have different layouts for `landscape` and `portrait`, and I do not wish to handle the layout changes manually.

**Edit 2:** I have come up with a way to get `configChanges` to work when using different layouts by using `SurfaceView` within the layouts and handling the layout change in `onConfigurationChanged` with `setContentView` and `MediaPlayer` to switch its display when the layout is changed.
Now, I just need a way to retain the `MediaPlayer` across orientation changes.

Comment: If this code is executing with in a `Fragment` one *possibility* is to use [setRetainInstance(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29) to ensure the fragment is **not** destroyed and recreated during a configuration change.

Comment: The code is currently being called within a `FragmentActivity`, but would moving the MediaPlayer into it's own `Fragment` class allow me to retain the video?

Comment: It was just a suggestion I thought you might want to look into. I'm not 100% sure it will retain the video's position.